# Regex in MongoDB is not matching special characters

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, special-characters, string-matching

I want to search values having special characters such as `? ! $ / . @ > #`  in a document.

I want to search values such as `?test`,

For example,

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : /.*?test.*/i });
```

OR

```
db.myCollection.find({ myKey : { '$regex' : '.*?test.*','$options' : 'i' });
```

What should I change here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-escape the special character:

```
db.collection.find({
  myKey: {
    $regex: "\\?test",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/oaRlSJvFNG_

Comment: Why the downvotes? What's wrong with this?

Comment: Hey Daniel. It worked for everything except for "#". Any solution for that? (Not sure about the downvotes. that ain't me though)